# Извлечь данные из списка словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, словари

как извлечь вложенный словарь в список, присвоить переменной этот ответ:

```
{
    'order_id': '1243660600',
    'created': '1537954081',
    'type': 'sell',
    'pair': 'USD_RUB',
    'quantity': '1.90032194',
    'price': '80',
    'amount': '152.0257552'
}
```

как извлечь определённое значение показали здесь *ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861680/Как-извлечь-значение-ключа-из-списка/861710#861710* извлечь по индексу знаю как,добавить `[0]`,но что если в разнобой придут данные внутри списка. питон 3.7

```
activeorder = [
    {'order_id': '1243660600', 'created': '1537954081', 'type': 'sell', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '1.90032194', 'price': '80', 'amount': '152.0257552'},
    {'order_id': '1243621115', 'created': '1537953105', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '2', 'price': '21.9887535', 'amount': '43.977507'},
    {'order_id': '1243621096', 'created': '1537953105', 'type': 'buy', 'pair': 'USD_RUB', 'quantity': '2', 'price': '31.9887535', 'amount': '63.977507'}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Откройте для себя Pandas:

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(activeorder)

In [4]: df
Out[4]:
        amount     created    order_id     pair       price    quantity  type
0  152.0257552  1537954081  1243660600  USD_RUB          80  1.90032194  sell
1    43.977507  1537953105  1243621115  USD_RUB  21.9887535           2   buy
2    63.977507  1537953105  1243621096  USD_RUB  31.9887535           2   buy

In [5]: df[(df['pair'] == 'USD_RUB') & (df['type'] == 'sell')]
Out[5]:
        amount     created    order_id     pair price    quantity  type
0  152.0257552  1537954081  1243660600  USD_RUB    80  1.90032194  sell

In [6]: df[(df['pair'] == 'USD_RUB') & (df['type'] == 'sell')].to_dict('record')
Out[6]:
[{'amount': '152.0257552',
  'created': '1537954081',
  'order_id': '1243660600',
  'pair': 'USD_RUB',
  'price': '80',
  'quantity': '1.90032194',
  'type': 'sell'}]
```

альтернативный, SQL-подобный вариант:

```
In [9]: df.query("pair == 'USD_RUB' and order_id in ['1243660600','1243621096']")
Out[9]:
        amount     created    order_id     pair       price    quantity  type
0  152.0257552  1537954081  1243660600  USD_RUB          80  1.90032194  sell
2    63.977507  1537953105  1243621096  USD_RUB  31.9887535           2   buy

In [10]: df.query("pair == 'USD_RUB' and order_id in ['1243660600','1243621096']").to_dict('records')
Out[10]:
[{'amount': '152.0257552',
  'created': '1537954081',
  'order_id': '1243660600',
  'pair': 'USD_RUB',
  'price': '80',
  'quantity': '1.90032194',
  'type': 'sell'},
 {'amount': '63.977507',
  'created': '1537953105',
  'order_id': '1243621096',
  'pair': 'USD_RUB',
  'price': '31.9887535',
  'quantity': '2',
  'type': 'buy'}]
```

Comment: нет уж спасибо ))) вот определённое значение извлекается result_dic = [dic['order_id'] for dic in list_ if dic['type'] == 'buy'] просто и в одну строчку!!

Comment: @Venus, жалко что вы не сумели разглядеть потенциал данного модуля. Он идеально подходит для ваших структур данных и ваших задач...